# Image Error "i.stack.imgur.com redirected you too many times"

Tags: support

All browsers, Windows 10.

As of last night images from i.stack.imgur.com have been broken for me. In Chrome, attempts to load the image directly result in the 'redirected you too many times' error. Last night, the problem was just in Chrome, but now it's in all browsers. Deleting cookies has not helped. Is this problem shared? Is there a known fix, or is it server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a issue affecting more then just you. There were four of us in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46088523#46088523) with this problem. It has happened before (like when s3 went down), and will probably happen again. SE and imgur will fix it. Nothing we can do, and no there is no need to re-upolad images to "fix" them.

There were a few reports ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313775/278094), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313779/278094), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313790/278094)) of this over on the main meta. For some (me included) it seems to be better.